# Is it possible to make a phone call IN the Flutter app without leaving the app?

Tags: android, ios, flutter

I am starting the work on the application where one of the functionalities is let's say, "context call", so app will let the user call someone on the fly.

Due to the nature of the app (used on car holder mostly), it would be nice to not leave the application (to not loose map view etc) while calling.

Is it possible at all? If so, how?

All that I am finding is triggering "normal" call which of course, leaves the app in the background.

Comment: In Android it sounds like you are trying to implement [Integrated Calling](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/telecom#integrateCalling) but most of the details would interact with the Android framework and not be written with Flutter.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but maybe this package can help https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_callkeep.